# .click syntax issue, Selenium, JAVA, Eclipse, Junit, EDGE browser

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, syntax

I am learning to automate using the following combo, Selenium, JAVA, Eclipse, Junit with windows 10 EDGE browser.
All the apps were downloaded and installed within the last week (16/05/17) so version numbers should be pretty current as of time of writting.

I am starting simple.
I want to be able to automate the following,

01) launch Edge browser

02) open URL (www.stackoverflow.com)

03) click "Log In" button (which I think is actually text, css'd with a hyperlink?)

The expected outcome is, stackoverflow login webpage is navigated to/displayed.

I have successfully launched the browser with the desired URL.
I know the code is finding the various elements associated to the "Log In" button by printing the found element details to the eclipse console window.
When I attempt to apply the .click() syntax to the element/attribute nothing occurs.

Can anyone tell me if I am applying the .click() syntax correctly/incorrectly?
I am applying it to the wrong element/attribute?

## My Java code is as follows,

```
package seleniumTestPackage006;

import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

public class Login006
{   
@Test

public void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    // ++ CREATE WEBDRIVER REFERENCE ++
    WebDriver driver;

    // ++ LAUNCH EDGE BROWSER ++
    driver = new EdgeDriver();

    // ++ OPEN THE WEBPAGE ++
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");

    // ++ SET TIME DELAY #01 ++
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // ++ FIND ELEMENT TO OPERATE ON ++
    /*WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.className("login-link"));*/
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='login']"));

    // ++ PRINT LOGIN LINK URL TO CONSOLE ++
    System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));

    // ++ SET TIME DELAY #02 ++
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // ++ CLICK ON LOGIN ++
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='login']")).click();
    /*driver().findElement(By.className("login-link")).cli‌​ck();*/
  }
}
```

Comment: the xpath you are using results in **4 elemetns** element identifier should be uniquely  identify element you want to click.  try this `.login-link.btn-clear`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you qualify the code further please. ie, can you wire the line of code in context. ie, //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login-link btn-clear']")).click();

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".login-link.btn-clear"))`

Comment: Thank you. If we are agreed that this is the correct element ".login-link.btn-clear" then when i execute the following code, why does the .click function not do anything?      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".login-link.btn-clear")).click();

Comment: is it working with other browsers ? if yes, this is specific to Edge, Edge sometimes gives such issue. in this case click using javascript or choose another identifier, parent or child element and it should work.

Comment: Unfortunatly i cannot be sure regarding alternative browser for the following reason. The firefox browser does launch to the correct webpage as per EDGE but does not do anything when .click() command is applied. I am getting an error message in the eclipse console for the firefox launch though, 1494944712525 addons.manager ERROR startup failed:

Comment: ok, have tried the code against firefox and as per last statement, the browser launches on the desired initial webpage, (ie www.stackoverflow.com) then nothing happens and the .click() function to navigate tot he stack overflow login screen does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without any implicit wait following code works with Firefox and should work with EdgeDriver as well, I don't see any issue.

```
@Test
public void login(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".login-link.btn-clear")).click();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and comments. I have tried your code against my set up and it is still not working for me, so I can only assume i have a set up issue. I will look into this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just to follow up on this. I have executed both your code and my code against an older version of firefox which means i could eliminate the gecko driver. The code worked.

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling all the software back to the most current versions, the JAVA code now works. Thanks for all your assistance Gaurang.

Comment: Also found the following inclusion of javascript code to perform the click function worked as a workaround for installation which had the .click() issue.
{
 @Test
 public void login(){ 
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
 //++JAVASCRIPT DRIVER++
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
 //++ESTABLISH ELEMENT TO OPERATE ON++
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".login-link.btn-clear"));
 //++EXECUTE JAVASCRIPT TO PERFORM CLICK FUNCTION++
  jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
 }